# Plutus week 6 - Oracle example smart contract removed

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, oracles, week06

Previously in Plutus pioneer program Week 6 shows how to implement an Oracle, now the example code has been removed.

Is this because the way to implement Oracles has changed? and the previous approach is not applicable anymore?

Comment: I can't say why they would have removed it. But Vasil does allow for much better Oracles with "reference" outputs. They might provide an example of that, but the old model isn't invalidated with the Vasil upgrades.

Comment: I'll take a look the Vasil improvements, thank you @MitchellTurner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Plutus Pioneer Program is iterative, thus the code in the repo can change between iterations.

However, if I'm not wrong, you can find the oracle example here: https://github.com/functionally/mantis-oracle/blob/main/src/Mantra/Oracle.hs

Answer (score 0):

Here is [the link](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/tree/8cbc68d146c82cc95d9be44c30e049aba3774003/code/week06) to the branch. In case anyone wanna check it out.